# Firebase functions with cloud sql

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-sql

is it possible to connect to my MySql Db (Google Cloud SQL) with a Firebase function (Not google cloud function)? I found an old question about that, from a couple of years ago, and at that point it was not possible.. Does anyone know if it is possible now?